# strncmp fails in parser function

Tags: c, embedded

I can't find the problem in my parse() function. Short intro:
I'm sending  "boot\r\n" from my terminal program, the parse() function gets called, the strncmp(buffer, "boot",4) never gets into the if branch??
At the moment I can't see the wood for the trees.
Afterwards the string which is returned from the parse() function is given to the remove_cr_lf_chars() function. I need to remove these characters to be able to compare the string with image names, which of course don't have any '\r' or '\n' characters.

```
static char *parse(void)
{
    static char buffer[100];
    char *p = buffer;
    char c;

    do {
        while (!(USART1->SR & USART_FLAG_RXNE));
        *p++ = c = ((char)USART1->DR);
    } while (c != '\r' && p-buffer < sizeof buffer-1);
    *p = '\0';

    if (strncmp(buffer, "boot", 4))
    {
        p = buffer+4;
        /* skip to argument, p might point to '\0' if none */
        while (*p != '\0' && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\r')) p++;
            return p;
    }
    return NULL;
}

static void remove_cr_lf_chars(char *dst)
{
    for (; *dst != '\0'; dst++)
        if (*dst != '\r' && *dst != '\n') dst++;
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `while (!(USART1->SR & USART_FLAG_RXNE));`  Be an infinite loop? or There is no meaning.

Comment: there is a timeout, running in the background

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `strncmp` returns 0 when there is a match. You need to invert your condition:

```
if (!strncmp(buffer, "boot", 4)) ... // Means "if buffer is equal to "boot" "
```

> **Return value:**
>   Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
>   A zero value indicates that the characters compared in both strings form the same string.
>   A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Comment: ... or compare with 0, since the return value isn't boolean (it's an integer either `< 0`, `== 0` or `> 0`) it's kind of mixing things up to treat it as a bool. I'd use `if (strncmp(buffer, "boot", 4) == 0)` to make it clear.

Comment: @unwind To tell you the truth, I was with the `== 0` camp for a very long time, using `!` only with boolean expressions. However, after watching dozens of very good programmers all using `!` with `strcmp` I changed my mind, and made a specific "mental exception" for situations when I use `strcmp` for equality comparisons only. I do see your side of the argument, though.

Answer (score 3):

`strncomp` returns 0 if the two compared strings are equal. Hence, you need to modifiy your condition at line 13. For instance, you could write :

```
if ( strncmp(buffer, "boot", 4) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `strcmp` and `strncmp` return `0` when there is a match.

You should use `if (!strncmp(buffer, "boot", 4))`.